# PrimeNg 8 Messages in Angular 8 Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'p-messages'

Tags: angular, primeng

```
I am using PrimeNg 8.2.9 following the examples here

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v8.2 ... #/messages
```

Getting the following error

Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'p-messages'.

```
using this in my html

<p-messages [(value)]="msgs" [closable]="false"></p-messages>
<button type="button" (click)="show()">Show</button>
<button type="button" (click)="clear()">Hide</button>
```

my ts. uses

```
res.errors.forEach(s => this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Info Message', detail: s.msg }));
```

No Idea, please help

Here is my app.module, this has everything I am importing and using

imports of app.module

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MessagesModule } from 'primeng/messages';
import {MessageModule} from 'primeng/message';



rest of ngModule

   
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent 
    
  ],
  imports: [
    
    MessagesModule ,
    MessageModule
  ],
  providers: [
    Title,
    LookupService,
    AppSettingsService,
    ConfirmationService,
    RoutePermissionService,
    LoginGuardService,
    MessageService 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [ModalComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: and you only have one module, app.module ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to import the necessary modules in `app.module` :

```
import {MessagesModule} from 'primeng/messages';
import {MessageModule} from 'primeng/message';

...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MessagesModule,
    MessageModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
...
```

Comment: here is my app.module

Comment: @ChinaSyndrome can you edit your question and add app.module ?

Comment: I did, site errrord with the entire thing so I have to strip it down.